# How can I stop background process in Windows 10 which I don't know the name?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, windows-services

I have deleted exe file of that process,so every time the service runs in background,it can't get that file.
How can I stop this service which I have no idea the name?
The path it's showing is "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\iufdtgfh\tvihwtdb.exe".

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of that service in task manager or process explorer or process hacker?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this happens when the computer is starting, that some system
process starts the process of `tvihwtdb.exe` which you have deleted.

To trace which system process is starting `tvihwtdb.exe`, you could use the
free [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

As this is happening during boot, you will need to use the Boot Time Logging
option of Process Explorer, then search within the log for `tvihwtdb.exe`.

Be warned that this slows down very noticeably the boot process, so ensure
it is not still turned on for your next boot.

See the following:

- [An easy way to measure computer reboot and logon times](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/robertsmith/2017/07/19/an-easy-way-to-measure-computer-reboot-and-logon-times/)
- [How To Enable System Boot Time Logging using Process Monitor Tool](https://www.msigeek.com/6231/how-to-enable-system-boot-time-logging-using-process-monitor-tool)