# ANONYM USER whatis this ? i never saw this before

Tags: virus, malware, windows-11, privacy, spyware

I was searching for some info on `sdhl.dat` and found this:
[image: Was searching for infos on (sdhl.dat) and found this]

Hello

I have a `.dat` file on my PC and every time I try to delete it, it comes back after restarting the PC. After some search I found this "anonymous registration". Should I be worried about it? Can this be a virus? I have already checked it on VirusTotal and Malwarebytes and it was safe but I still have my concerns over this `.dat` file. The only thing I found was that the game Valorant creates some `.dat` files on some users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON is a special pseudo user account in Windows.
It is
[defined](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-special-identities-groups#anonymous-logon)
by Microsoft as a "special identity":

> Anonymous Logon
>
> Any user who accesses the system through an anonymous logon has the
> Anonymous Logon identity. This identity allows anonymous access to
> resources, such as a web page that is published on corporate servers.
> The Anonymous Logon group is not a member of the Everyone group by
> default.

This allows access to the file by any network or web user that
has the permission to use the computer or web-app without specifying
a password.
It's most commonly found in web-apps, if you're using your computer
as web-server via IIS.

In short, this is a harmless file permission, that commonly would never
have any effect (unless the file is part of a web-app or is shared
over a network in which anonymous access is allowed).

Comment: Thank u alot for helping !!! just another question if u have time. i got this sdhl.dat file and i dont know what it is or from where it comes is there a way to check it ?

Comment: There is no reference to such a file on the internet and it doesn't exist on my computer. Perhaps the folder in which it's found would give an indication of the process that created it.

Comment: the thing is it doesnt go to a folder it gets "created" on the desktop

Comment: You could delete the file and use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out which process is creating it. If this is happening during boot, you need boot logging - see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1380370/8672).